# programmatically load yaml parameters in C

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, rosparam, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm trying to load a YAML file into the parameter server programmatically in C++.

I know it is possible with Python, from this question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/58819/programatically-load-yaml-config-file-to-the-parameter-server/), but I couldn't find a way to do it in C++.

I'm using Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359158/programmatically-load-yaml-parameters-in-c/) by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2020-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp

Checkout the https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
yaml_params_ = YAML::LoadFile(yaml_filename);

for (YAML::const_iterator it = yaml_params_.begin(); it != yaml_params_.end(); ++it) {
    nh.setParam(it->first.as<std::string>(), it->second.as<double>());
}
```

PS: Not sure if there is a better way, but this is how I do it. Obviously, there is [ddynamic_reconfigure](https://github.com/pal-robotics/ddynamic_reconfigure) & [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials), where you can store the params to `*.yaml` and save/load them as needed.

---

Originally posted by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) with karma: 257 on 2020-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-11**:
For future readers: I believe it's important to point out that in case a node does this, and the node is started via a `.launch` file, parameters set by this node will *not* be visible to other nodes, *unless* they are started *after* the parameter-setting node (and there is no way to enforce that, at least not in ROS 1).

Seeing as the order of starting nodes with `roslaunch` is not guaranteed, there is no way to guarantee these parameters will show up on the parameter server before they are accessed by other nodes.

This is one of the reasons why parameters are set *first* by `roslaunch`, and only then are nodes started.

**Comment by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on 2020-08-11**:
But how about cached parameters? [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Cached_Parameters) it says that the nodes are notified when such parameters are changed, but it is not clear how...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @praskot, but I did not specify that I don't want to depend explicitly on `yaml-cpp`. I've resolved by invoking the `rosparam` command from the code. Assuming that `cfg_file_path` is a valid `boost::filesystem::path` object:

```
  namespace fsys = boost::filesystem;
  if(!fsys::exists(cfg_file_path) ||
     !(fsys::is_regular_file(cfg_file_path) || fsys::is_symlink(cfg_file_path)))
  {
    ROS_WARN_STREAM("Could not open camera param file " << cfg_file_path.string());
  } else {
    // load the YAML file using the external rosparam command
    std::string command = "rosparam load " + cfg_file_path.string();
    int result = std::system(command.c_str());
    if(result != 0){
      ROS_WARN_STREAM("Could not set config file " << cfg_file_path.string()
                      << " to the parameter server.");
    }
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) with karma: 102 on 2020-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phymin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32008/phymin/) on 2022-07-22**:
Thanks, this works for me, so does this mean we cannot use code(not the code with command) to load parameter file at runtime?